# javascript function override

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to completely override the function callwithargs that accepts some arguments with another new function callwithargs with no arguments?

```
function callwithargs(a, b, c){
       if(arg.length){
        do this
     }else{
        do something else
    }
    }

function callwithargs(){
  do a new thing
}
```

Comment: Yes it is. In fact you just did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, javascript doesn't include the number of parameters as a unique identifier of the function.  `function callwithargs(...)` defines a property of the global object named `callwithargs`.  When you define that property again you overwrite it.

In fact you can also override it by saying `callwithargs = 2` for instance, which will then overwrite the property with a number value

Answer (score 1):

I've done something similar and I hope this leads you to your answer.  Essentially in my case, the function was attached to an object, and after the object was initialized I replaced that function with my new function like so:

```
var oldFunction = myObject.theFunction;
myObject.theFunction = function () {
    // my new function
    var result = oldFunction.apply(this, arguments); // Calls the old function using the arguments keyword

    return result;
};
```